# I'm trying to understand an optimization for improving minification in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, minify

While digging into the [uniform.js](http://uniformjs.com/) source code I found this (on line [#333](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/blob/master/jquery.uniform.js#L333)):

```
/**
* Meaningless utility function. Used mostly for improving minification.
*
* @return false
*/
function returnFalse() {
  return false;
}
```

This function is called in some places (the trend seems to be in situations where a `false` value is used in a JavaScript Object Literal like this (from line [#351](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/blob/master/jquery.uniform.js#L351))

```
bindMany($elem, options, {
  'selectstart dragstart mousedown': returnFalse
});
```

But not in situations where false is explicitly returned.  My question is why is this said to improve minification?  My first thought was that by pulling `false` into a function the function could be renamed to say 'a', so places where `false` was expected it could be represented as `a()`, but this doesn't seem to provide much of a benefit for what I think is a cost of an extra function in the execution. Is there something much more obvious that I do not understand about this?

Comment: I believe it is better than putting an anonymous function there that returns false. From what I remember, jQuery also had a `returnFalse()` function in the core. **Edit:** Yes, it still does in version [1.9.1](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js).

Comment: Ohh I hadn't noticed that the function was being returned not it's return value

Comment: Apparently, if the code does what I think, you're binding a handler to those events which returns false, and by returning false inside an event handler in jQuery is effectively the same as calling `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Though, if a library uses jQuery, one could assign `false` directly to it instead of a function that returns false, as `false` is treated as a special value that does the same as I commented above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should note that in your example `returnFalse` is not getting called, it's getting passed. It's being used to prevent the default behavior of the provided events.

This technique of having a utility function to prevent the default behavior prevents the need to create new anonymous functions to do the same thing multiple times:

```
$('foo').on('something', function () {
    return false;
});
//minified to something like:
$(a).on(b,function(){return !1});
```

vs

```
$('foo').on('something', returnFalse); 
//minified to something like:
function c(){return !1}
$(a).on(b,c);
```

That all being said, it's a misguided means of minification, as jQuery allows `false` to be passed in place of event handlers to prevent the default behavior:

```
$('foo').on('something', false);
//minified to something like:
$(a).on(b,!1);
```

Comment: Yes `$(a).on(b,!1);` seems like reading the output of google closure. `=]`